# When I examine argv[1] and argv[2] I can't open and write to them

Tags: c, argv

When I examine `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, I can't open and write to them! If I don't write the examine, part all things work. I have to use command line parameters as well.

The main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
```

a part of

```
while (i < MAXADAT && kilep)
    {
        hianyzofajleredmeny = 1;
        if ((argv[2][i] == '.' && argv[2][i + 1] == 'c' && argv[2][i + 2] == 's' && argv[2][i + 3] == 'v' && argv[2][i + 4] == '\0'))
        {
            hianyzofajleredmeny = 0;
            kilep = 0;
        }
        i++;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual code which is not working. BTW your long line here can be replaced by `!strcmp( argv[2] + i, ".csv" )`

Comment: Here is a link!
The whole program!
Basicly i open a cvs file ad make with them task than i write it a new csv file!
http://www.speedyshare.com/JaA7S/VEGLEGES-vegleg.txt

Comment: Apparently, I have to download a .exe to get the content from that site.  Quite apart from the fact that a `.exe` won't work on a Mac, I wouldn't use a site that requires their downloader for something as trivial as this.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jBA3TRTQnKQ7fValxBQdRITfodEk639_DIw7tMF7ZME/edit?usp=sharing
I hope you see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much magic involved.  You don't show enough code for us to know what you're really up to, but this code opens the files specified in `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file1 file2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *dot1 = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
    if (dot1 == 0 || strcmp(dot1, ".csv") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: file %s is not a CSV file\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp1 == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open %s for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *dot2 = strrchr(argv[2], '.');
    if (dot2 == 0 || strcmp(dot2, ".csv") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: file %s is not a CSV file\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (fp2 == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open %s for writing\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    size_t nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp)) != 0)
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), nbytes, fp2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

It would be sensible to error check `fclose(fp2)`; if it fails, then the output file was not created successfully.  It is less crucial to error check `fclose(fp1)` in general.

The code would benefit from error reporting functions so that the error reporting blocks take up just one line each instead of four, but writing a function to do that job is just a little more complex than you're ready to deal with.  Not radically more complex, but enough that I'm not going to overload you with it.  The code is very verbose as a result, though.

The code also assumes you have C99 or C11 so you can declare variables at arbitrary points in a function.  If you're stuck with C89, then (a) it is time to upgrade to where you can use a standard that's only 15 years old instead of 25 years old, and (b) you'll have to move all the variable declarations to the top of the function and change the initializations into assignments.